# Bind property to each ListBox.ItemTemplate created

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, listboxitem

I'm totally new to wpf and silverlight, and I have A LOT to learn...

I've got a listbox which contain a template

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" x:Name="list">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate" >
            <Grid Name="{Binding Id}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Txt}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

i need to assign a `AutomationProperties.AutomationId` to each list item, like in

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="lb_a" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="lb_1">
    <Grid Name="grid_a">
        <TextBlock Text="aa"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem x:Name="lb_b" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="lb_2">
    <Grid Name="grid_b">
        <TextBlock Text="bb"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
...
```

how can i do?
is that even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set your attached property in `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" x:Name="list">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding MyAutomationIdProperty}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @Doc Try `TargetType="ListBoxItem"`. dkozl, I already edited your answer, it's pending approval.

Comment: @Doc, missed Silverlight tag. John is correct, just remove `{x:Type }` bit and should work. Check updated answer